# 'What's new' on tlmgr

Tags: texlive, updating

I'm using `tlmgr` to update packages. Once a week I use it and update all.

But some times I'd like to know what are the changes on some packages.

Is it possible to show this? Maybe clicking somewhere to see *what's new file*.

I know that I can find this on CTAN, but what about on `tlmgr`?

**ps.** I forgot to say that I'm using a GUI. So I can see what is available to update.

Comment: I usually look at http://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/?sortby=date If you want to see a particular revision, go to http://tug.org/svn/texlive?view=revision&sortby=date&revision=32831 (change the number with what you find in the `tlmgr` window.

Comment: So everything it was updated using `tlmgr` I could find on that link? Nice!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you perform a [TeX Live update](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55459/5764), the specific packages that were updated is logged in `tlmgr.log` (located in `~/texmf-var/web2c/`). It looks like this:

```
...
[Thu Jan 30 16:39:24 2014] update: sa-tikz (32788 -> 32815)
[Thu Jan 30 16:39:28 2014] update: texlive-msg-translations (32801 -> 32813)
[Thu Jan 30 16:39:32 2014] update: texlive-scripts (32798 -> 32811)
[Thu Jan 30 16:39:35 2014] update: xetex-itrans (24105 -> 32810)
[Fri Jan 31 13:56:10 2014] update: babel-spanish (30295 -> 32825)
[Fri Jan 31 13:56:25 2014] update: pst-3dplot (27233 -> 32824)
```

You see the date of the update/install, as well as the type (whether it was a removal/install/update/...), the name of the package, as well as the update revision reference (from -> to).

Now you can visit [TeX Live Master trunk](http://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/) and enter the revision number as see the changes. For example, the above [revision to 32824](http://tug.org/svn/texlive?view=revision&sortby=file&revision=32824) lists:

[image]

Comment: I have only `~/.texlive2013/texmf-var/web2c` but no `log` file there.

Comment: @Sigur: According to the [`tlmgr` man page](http://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/tlmgr.html#OPTIONS), the option `--package-logfile <file>` specifies where this file resides: "`tlmgr` logs all package actions (install, remove, update, failed updates, failed restores) to a separate log file, by default `TEXMFSYSVAR/web2c/tlmgr.log`. This option allows you to specific a different file for the log." Perhaps you're using a GUI that specifies it differently?

Answer (score 14):

If you use a graphical interface, the list of updates is available for inspection prior to doing the actual download. Here's an example with the Tcl-Tk interface

[image]

Here's the same with TeX Live Utility (Mac OS X)

[image]

Say you want to see what's changed in `quoting`: the remote version is 32818; go to

```
http://tug.org/svn/texlive?view=revision&sortby=date&revision=32818
```

(change the final number for the revision you want to see). This is a link to the master repository; going there will open the window

[image]

The “text-changed” links are the most useful.

The most recent changes are reachable at http://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/?sortby=date

Comment: Exactly what I need. I bookmarked that link now. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Try

```
tlmgr update --all --dry-run
```

this will give you the list of package to be updated. (this option means "explain what you are going to do, but do not perform the action, see http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-dry1.htm). Then you need to go to CTAN if you want to see what exactly changed in each package.

Comment: What is that option for?

Comment: Option `--dry-run` means do everything BUT the actual update.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused. I use `tlmgr` to update some packages and other tools. It suggests me and I choose what to update. Usually I choose `all`. But what is the `actual update`? I have no idea.

Comment: Well, `tlmgr update --all` looks into a repository, finds packages to update, downloads them and installs.  `--dry-run` means "do not download and install, just show what are you going to do".

Comment: surely.  here you are