# What do these numbers in the tlmgr update mean?

Tags: texlive, updating

Whenever I update my TeXLive distribution by using `tlmgr`, I get in the output numbers such as these:

> 35545 -> 36463

What do they mean?

Comment: Every `tlmgr` package has a unique identification number, which increases at each update, taking the first “free” number.

Comment: Related: ['What's new' on `tlmgr`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/156908/5764)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first number is the revision installed locally before the update (or `-` if not present on your system), and the second number is the server revision, that is, the one currently being installed/removed (or `-` if not on the server).

From the output of `tlmgr --help` (this is from the machine-readable output section, but the information is the same):

```
*localrev*
    The revision number of the installed package, or "-" if it is not
    present locally.

*serverrev*
    The revision number of the package on the server, or "-" if it is
    not present on the server.
```

The revision number sequence is *not* tied to the package. This number is a simple counter that is incremented on an update to *any* package. A new update takes the next available revision number.

Comment: Thanks. And is there some place where I kind look up what changes does a particular revision have?

Comment: You can go to [TeX Live SVN](http://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/) and enter the revision number to see the changes on that commit.